# spring.security.core and defaultTargetUrl

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using spring-security-core:2.0-RC5 with grail 2.3.3, and controling web page access via the Requestmap dB system.

I am having problems logging into the app and directing the app to the appropriate web page once authenticated.

I have used the defaultTargetUrl configuration setting to define where to go after a successful logon.

This being a development application the root URL is: http://localhost:9002/VidPlay

I have two users with different roles:

John1 - with ROLE_ADMIN + ROLE_USER

Mike1 - ROLE_USER only

If the defaultTargetUrl is set to /home/index

Logging in as John1 authenticates and goes to URL: http://localhost:9002/VidPlay successfully. Why does it not go to http://localhost:9002/VidPlay/home/index which I can access once logged in?

Logging in as Mike1 authenticates directed to URL: http://localhost:9002/VidPlay but correctly fails access. Again why does it not go to http://localhost:9002/VidPlay/home/index which I can access once logged in?

It seems that both logins get redirected to http://localhost:9002/VidPlay but I don't know why despite the fact that I can go to these pages once logged in?

If the defaultTargetUrl is set to /Requestmap/index.

Logging in as John1 authenticates and goes to URL: http://localhost:9002/VidPlay/Requestmap/index successfully.

Logging in as Mike1 authenticates and is redirected to URL: http://localhost:9002/VidPlay but correctly fails access.

It seems to redirect Mike1 to http://localhost:9002/VidPlay. Once logged as Mike1 I can then go to http://localhost:9002/VidPlay/Requestmap/index. Why does it not go to http://localhost:9002/VidPlay/Requestmap/index which I can access once logged in?

Thanks Mike

Comment: Try setting grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true

Comment: @Sudhir N - yes that's done the job - thanks.

Comment: Posted it as answer below

Answer (score 0):

When user access an url which is secure, but user is not logged in, spring security will redirect user to login screen. User will be redirected back to original urlafter successful login.

You can set the configuration alwaysUseDefault = true that will make spring always security redirect users to configured defaultTargetUrl after login

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
```